# How to have a dropdown searchbox that filters table results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am still new to programming and currently I encounter a problem. I have used a code from W3schools which allows me to filters the table when it matches the search result. However, I want to make it better for the users of the website. I want to allow them to be able to search through the searchbox and also give them the option to select a dropdown from the box which returns the same result.

Below is the code I have used for HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.."><table id="myTable">
<tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Fruit Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Place of Origin</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Black Berry</td>
    <td>North America</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Durian</td>
    <td>SouthEast Asia</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>South Korea</td>
</tr></table>
```

And the JavaScript used:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm sorry for this mess, in short, these were taken from the *W3school* site with some changes. Instead of having just a search box, I want to implement a drop down with the search box if it is possible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you will have searchbox as well as dropdown?

Comment: Yes sir, I want a searchbox with dropdown

Comment: Ok, so there is already a searchbox in your code, and you want to add dropdown. What will be the options of dropdown? Will it be the fruit names?

Comment: Yes the fruit names will be used as the dropdown, so if a user wants to search for a fruit, they can either click the dropdown, the table will be filtered or they can type out the fruit name and the table will be filtered.

Comment: And what if user selects one option from dropdown and also enters something in searchbox??

Comment: If they selects an option, it will filter to that fruit. And if they enter something, the filter will override. Basically, the main idea of what I'm thinking of is to allow people to see the origins of the fruits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, below is the updated code with search box as well as dropdown that will filter rows:

```js
function myFunction(searchTerm) {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  filter = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}

var options = $("#fruitOptions");
$("#myTable tr:not(.header)").each(function() {
  options.append($("<option />").val($(this).find("td:first-child").text()).text($(this).find("td:first-child").text()));
});

$("#myInput").on('input', function() {
  myFunction($(this).val());
});

$("#fruitOptions").on('change', function() {
  myFunction($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names..">
<select id="fruitOptions">
<option value=''>- Please select -</option></select>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Fruit Name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Place of Origin</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Asia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Black Berry</td>
    <td>North America</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Durian</td>
    <td>SouthEast Asia</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
    <td>South Korea</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Edit: Hi sir, I've tried the code, when I run the snippet, it works, but when I apply it on my code, the dropdown and also the searchbox is not working. Do you know the problem for this?

Comment: @Azvier this code should work. have you included `jQuery` library in your project ?? or are you getting any errors in console ?

Comment: @Azvier What errors do you see in the console? High chances, you haven't included the JQuery library.

Comment: @mrid Hi sorry for the late reply sir, I followed the code, and included the jQuery CDN. I checked the console but it does not show anything

Comment: Edit: The code works on my editor now, thank you so much sir. I put the script in the wrong place. My apologies.

Comment: You're welcome! You can upvote and accept the answer. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

> HTML

```
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
    <select id="selectItems">
        <option>NA</option>
    </select>
<table id="myTable">

    <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:60%;">Fruit Name</th>
        <th style="width:40%;">Place of Origin</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apple</td>
        <td>Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Black Berry</td>
        <td>North America</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Durian</td>
        <td>SouthEast Asia</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Watermelon</td>
        <td>South Korea</td>
    </tr></table>
```

> Javascript:

```
function init()
{
 //insert item in dropdown from table.

 var html_for_elect = '';
 var itm_dd = document.getElementById("selectItems");

 table1 = document.getElementById("myTable");
 trtbl = table1.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 for (i = 0; i < trtbl.length; i++) {
            td = trtbl[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                html_for_elect = html_for_elect + "<option>"+td.innerHTML+"</option>";

            }
        }
itm_dd.innerHTML = html_for_elect;
}
init();
    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }




    }
    function myFunction1() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("selectItems");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("myInput").value= input.value;

    }

// myFunction1 can be use as (only use one of these myFunction1 functions):

function myFunction1() {

        document.getElementById("myInput").value= 
        document.getElementById("selectItems").value;
        myFunction();

    }
```

Comment: Hi I tried the code, but when I click on the dropdown value(I replaced the NA with the fruit names), the table is still the same

Comment: @azvier there no need to change the value of `dropdown` i create a function to initialize the dropdown from the table.you just put both three function I write there and a select element with on change event calling `myfunction1`.

Comment: Oh, my apologies sir. I've changed back the codes but only the search box work, while the drop down, it only have the option of NA.

Comment: If this code is useful than accept it as answer and upvote to help others.

Comment: I have upvoted but as I am a new member, it does not show the increment.